# Can anyone see why this program generates a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program to implement a map using a singly linked list. After writing and including this insert method the program generates a segmentation fault but i'm not sure where this comes from.

```
int map_insert(Map *theMap, char *theKey, void *theItem){

   node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

   node *cursor = theMap->root;

   while(cursor->next !=  NULL){
      cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    newNode->key = theKey;
    newNode->item = theItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    cursor->next = newNode;

    return (node *)newNode;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing as parameters to `map_insert`? Using a debugger, can you determine during which line's execution the seg fault occurs?

Comment: apart from the pointer that is returned as an int (which is probably the cause of the segfault): are you sure `theMap` is passed correctly (ie: is it a valid pointer), and is `theMap->root` valid (if it's `NULL`, `cursor->next` dereferences a NULL pointer) and check the return value of `malloc`, it _can_ return `NULL`. either way, compile with the `-g` flag (gcc), and step through the code (gdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node *cursor = theMap->root;`

I'm assuming if the map is empty, root will be NULL.

`while(cursor->next !=  NULL)`

If `root` was `NULL`, `cursor` is `NULL` as well, and you are dereferencing it when accessing the `next` field.

Perhaps change the while condition to:

`while (cursor && cursor->next)` ?

---

EDIT: Here's a full function that works:

```
node * map_insert(Map *theMap, char *theKey, void *theItem){

    node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    newNode->key = theKey;
    newNode->item = theItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    node *cursor = theMap->root;

    if (cursor) {
       while(cursor->next !=  NULL){
          cursor = cursor->next;
        }
        cursor->next = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        theMap->root = newNode;
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: that could be true, but how could you tell root is not a sentinel object? probably failed malloc will return a null too.

Comment: Well, true. And checking the malloc return value was suggested in a comment to the original question, but.. how often do you encounter bugs because malloc failed, compared to other common mistakes? When was the last time malloc failed for you?

Comment: Regarding sentinel objects, the code would likely have been structured differently if that was the case. Besides, I find it hard to believe someone would implement sentinel objects, and not have a pointer to the list tail.

Comment: int map_insert(Map *theMap, char *theKey, void *theItem){

   node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

   node *cursor = theMap->root;

   // map is empty, root is NULL
   if(cursor == NULL){
     cursor->key = theKey;
     cursor->item = theItem;
     cursor->next = NULL;
   }
   else{
   while(cursor->next !=  NULL){
      cursor = cursor->next;
    }

    newNode->key = theKey;
    newNode->item = theItem;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    cursor->next = newNode;
   }

    if(newNode != NULL)
      return 1;
    return 0;
}

Comment: I have that as my new function but it is still giving me a segmentation fault

Comment: That guarantees a segfault :) You are checking if cursor is NULL, and IF IT IS, you are dereferencing it. If the map is empty, you just need to do `theMap->root = newNode;`

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the function `map_insert` is

```
int map_insert(Map *theMap, char *theKey, void *theItem)
```

As you can see, it is designed to return an `int`. But you return a `node*`. Fix the problem by changing it to:

```
node* map_insert(Map *theMap, char *theKey, void *theItem){
```

---

The cast here:

```
return (node *)newNode;
```

is not required as `newNode` is already of type `node*`.

Comment: This had to have been at least a compile time warning.. But on a 32bit system, it would probably end up working.. I don't think that's the source of the segfault, but rather `cursor->next` when `cursor` is potentially NULL.